# Java JPQL, join table, many to many relation

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa, jpql

We are working on a project in school and we trying to use entity JPA. 
We have several tables in our Mysql database and the one we are using is taxonomy, term, campaign and term_campaign_relationship.

We have made an entity for campaign, term, and taxonomy. We would like to get all the terms that are related to a campaign and filtered by taxonomy id.

We have used the @ManyToMany JPQL with @JoinTable and joinColumns
With that we have received all the terms that are related with the campaign.

But how do we get the result filtered by the taxonomy id only?

The sql statement below shows the result we are looking for...

```
SELECT 
t.id, t.term_name, t.taxonomy_id
FROM
term t
    INNER JOIN
taxonomy ty ON ty.id = t.taxonomy_id
    INNER JOIN
campaign c ON c.id IN (SELECT 
        tc.campaign_id
    FROM term_campaign_relationship tc
    WHERE tc.term_id = t.id
)
WHERE c.id = 1 AND ty.id = 1;
```

This is from our campaign entity in java

```
@ManyToMany()
@JoinTable(
  name="term_campaign_relationship",
  joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="campaign_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
  inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="term_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
private Collection<Term> programTypes;
```

Please advise if we are missing anything...

Comment: show us the code to get the the taxonomy. you must have a query to get only the entity with id 1

Comment: Is this the solution you looked for?
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("Select x from taxonomy  x where x.id=:arg1");
query.setParameter("arg1", 1);

Comment: We don't have any use for the code to get the taxonomy. We just want to filter by it, so that we get all the terms belonging to campaign with the taxonomy_id 1.

Comment: We are still quite new. is your code the similar to use @JoinTable??

Comment: Ok, but you must have code to get the list of entities? You need the entities and you need  a EntityManager and Queries. Please have a look at a tutorial in the internet ....

Comment: We do use EntityManager. We were wondering if there were an easier way instead of using NameQuery
If we are using NameQuery, how will we establish a reference between term_campaign_relationship without making an entity for the specific table?

Comment: but it is easy .... if you query for all with id 1 you need to write a query. can you please mark my answer as accepted? thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the entity code of campaign, term and taxonom?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the solution you looked for?

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("Select tax from taxonomy tax where tax.id = :arg1"); 
query.setParameter("arg1", 1);
```